# How to correctly set dynamic lib path using CMake?

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, shared-libraries

I'm trying to use `OpenMP` on Mac.

After compiling, when running binary file,

I get

```
dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libomp.dylib
  Referenced from: ./lab1
  Reason: image not found
[1]    64552 trace trap  ./lab1
```

I used otool to find out what path it expects.

```
otool -L lab1
lab1:
        @rpath/libomp.dylib (compatibility version 5.0.0, current version 5.0.0)
        /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (compatibility version 1.0.0, current version 1226.10.1)
```

This required library `libomp.dylib` is at path `/usr/local/opt/llvm/lib`.

How to make the binary can find it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding the required path to the executable's rpaths by using a CMake `POST_BUILD` action:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET lab1 
    POST_BUILD COMMAND 
    ${CMAKE_INSTALL_NAME_TOOL} -add_rpath /usr/local/opt/llvm/lib
    $<TARGET_FILE:lab1>)
```

This only works if `lab1` is a CMake executable target that is created with `add_executable`.